# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level error is if player['health'] <= 0:

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

where is my error in this code still a begginer

```
player = {'name': 'Frankie', 'attack': 10, 'heal': 5, 'health': 200}
eliza = {'name': 'Eliza', 'attack': 5, 'health': 200}
game_running = True

while game_running == True:

    print('please select action')
    print('1) Attack')
    print('2) Heal')

    player_choice = input()

    if player_choice == '1':
        eliza['health'] = eliza['health'] - player['attack']
        player['health'] = player['health'] - eliza['attack']
        print(eliza['health'])
        print(player['health'])


    elif player_choice == "2":
        print('Heal player')
    else:
        print('Invalid Input')

     if player['health'] <= 0:
         game_running = False
```

my issue is this if player['health'] <= 0: where am i wrong

Comment: The last line of code with the 'if' statement causes the error. Shift back one space to align with the else statement from above.

Comment: i just did but im still getting the same error

Comment: I provided the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player = {'name': 'Frankie', 'attack': 10, 'heal': 5, 'health': 200}
eliza = {'name': 'Eliza', 'attack': 5, 'health': 200}
game_running = True

while game_running == True:

    print('please select action')
    print('1) Attack')
    print('2) Heal')

    player_choice = input()

    if player_choice == '1':
        eliza['health'] = eliza['health'] - player['attack']
        player['health'] = player['health'] - eliza['attack']
        print(eliza['health'])
        print(player['health'])


    elif player_choice == "2":
        print('Heal player')
    else:
        print('Invalid Input')

    if player['health'] <= 0:
        game_running = False
```

The code here runs, I tested it locally.

Suggestions:

1. Use PyCharm or other related IDE so that you can get accustomed and have an overview before running the script (in PyCharm you would get a red line telling you that there is a problem with indenting.
2. `while game_running` is sufficient, you do not have to explicitly write `while game_running == True`

Comment: idk what i did but i just closed it and re opened it in pycharm again and it fixed itslef not sure why that happend thank you guys

Comment: actually it did remove the while now lol and yes didn't realize my bad

Comment: can i ask another question in here

Comment: Shoot it; you can ask

Comment: well this whole code is from a youtube video guide of learning python with making a small game also explaing how everything works all i did was change the names andthe attacks power and stuff but im getting a lot of errors idk where i messed up im getting this error again having trouble refering to the names or the attack inside the { error is  if player['health'] <= 0: or eliza['health'] <= 0:
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The problem is the " : " after if player['health'] <=0. The correct code to write would be if player['health'] <=0 or eliza['health'] <=0 :

Comment: that actully worked idk how there was : somewhere in the code where it shouln't be there

Comment: can you look at my code again and tell me why the game keeps running after one of us dies or win then it keeps running it doesn't stop and reset and start again